# calculating x2 from poisson distributed data

Tags: matlab, statistics

So I have a table of values

```
v=0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
#times obs.: 5 19 23 21 14 12 3 2 1 0
```

I am supposed to calculate chi squared assuming the data fits a poisson dist. with mean u=3.
I have to group values >=6 all in one bin.

I am unsure of how to plot the poisson dist., and most of all how to control what goes into what bin, if that makes sense.

I have plotted a histogram using histc before..but it was with random numbers that I normalized. The amount in each bin was set for me. 
I am super new...sorry if this question sucks.

Comment: What language is this? (What is `mat`?)

Comment: Sorry, I was confused on what to put for the tag. I am using the student edition of MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

You use `bar` to plot a bar graph in matlab.

So this is what you do:

```
v=0:9;
f=[5 19 23 21 14 12 3 2 1 0];
fc=f(find(v<6));      % copy elements where v<=6 into a new array
fc(end+1)=sum(f(v=>6)); % append the sum of elements where v=>6 to that array
figure
bar(v(v<=6), fc);
```

That should do the trick...

Now you didn't actually ask about the chi squared calculation. I would urge you not to put values of v>6 all into one bin for that calculation, as it will give you a really bad result.

There is another technique: if you use the `hist` function, you can choose the bins - and Matlab will automatically put things that exceed the limits into the last bin. So if your observations were in the array `Obs`, you can do what was asked with:

```
h = hist(Obs, 0:6);
figure
bar(0:6, h)
```

The advantage is that you have the array `h` available (frequencies) for other calculations.

If you do instead

```
hist(Obs, 0:6)
```

Matlab will plot the graph for you in a single statement (but you don't have the values...)

Comment: This didnt work. This is the error I got: Attempt to execute SCRIPT bar as a function:
/Users/emilywelk/Desktop/OCE 260/Problem Set 4/bar.m

Error in stupidbar (line 8)
bar(v(v<=6), fc);

Comment: It seems you have a script defined in your path with the name `bar` (path given in error message) which overrides the built in function. Change the name of the file and try again...